# What is the best way to store 2d arrays in Redis?

Tags: node.js, database, redis

I want to store data that looks like this:

```
{ 
  20160120: [
    ["slug", "title", "date"],
    ["slug", "title", "date"],
    ["slug", "title", "date"]
  ]
}
```

What is the best way to do this in Redis?

Comment: How you are planning to read data from that structure?

Comment: I can iterate through each array @misterion - like 20160120[0]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each time you thinking about some complex structure in Redis you should think about right decomposition.

### Entry data with LIST

If your data has regular structure (like [named tuple](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) in python) - use LIST for storing ([more about this](https://redislabs.com/ebook/part-1-getting-started/chapter-1-getting-to-know-redis/1-2-what-redis-data-structures-look-like/1-2-2-lists-in-redis/)):

```
LPUSH entry:20160120:0 slug title date
LPUSH entry:20160120:1 slug title date
LPUSH entry:20160120:2 slug title date
```

This gives you

1. The most RAM saving way to store data.
2. The fastest iteration speed.

If your data has non regular structire - you HASH as in @h0x91B answer.

### First dimension?

Yes, you can use ZSET as @h0x91B suggest, but if you have no plans to delete entries from first dimenstion you can use plain incremental key to keep max index - `INCE ARRAY:20160120 1`. Use it like `max count` pattern, becouse of in most of cases you can just read you second dimension data without actual check if this data present of not.

For example for LIST case (LUA code, there KEYS is `20160120`):

```
  local maxCount = redis.call("GET", KEYS[1]);
  local ret = {};
  for i = 0, maxCount, 1 do
     table.insert(ret, redis.call("LRANGE", "entry:" .. KEYS[1] .. ":" .. i, 0, -1);
  end
  return ret ;
```

### ZSET way?

This way is somekind of hardcore but allows you to store and get data in one query and keep all data in one sorted set. Also, it may be more RAM saving if you have millions of entries (too much simple keys in Redis [can be a problem](http://redisplanet.com/redis/under-the-hood-of-redis-hash-part-1/)). So the way of [ZRANGEBYLEX](http://redis.io/commands/zrangebylex):

```
       |- key for your array
       |   |- index in first dimenstion 
       |   |   |-search pattern as first dimenstion key
       |   |   |       |-actual value
ZADD entry 0 20160120:slug
ZADD entry 0 20160120:title
ZADD entry 0 20160120:date
```

And query, for example all data from index 2 and 20160120 date:

```
ZRANGEBYLEX entry[20160120: +
```

Comment: If I were going with the your first list example - how would I query to get back all the data related to 20160120 ?

Comment: Update with example in `First dimension` case

Answer (score 1):

Many ZSET's if you need save order in Arrays, or use SET's if order not matter.

If SET's is to big for SMEMBERS use SSCAN to iterate over whole list.

Also you can use HSET and store your array entry in this way:

```
HMSET HSET:ENTRY:20160120:0 "slug" "slug-data1" "title" "title-data" "date" "date-data"
HMSET HSET:ENTRY:20160120:1 "slug" "slug-data2" "title" "title-data" "date" "date-data"
HMSET HSET:ENTRY:20160120:2 "slug" "slug-data3" "title" "title-data" "date" "date-data"

ZADD ENTRY:20160120 0 HSET:ENTRY:20160120:0 1 HSET:ENTRY:20160120:1 2 HSET:ENTRY:20160120:2
```

My opinion - HSET+ZSET for storing order is best way (in memory keys will be optimised so no extra memory will needed)

Comment: I don't want key names, for space saving. I just want an array of  values, which I would know the key to myself.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach that is sometimes suitable is to store the serialized array as a String (or perhaps as a member in another data structure if multiple such arrays exist). Keep in mind that both MessagePack and JSON have built-in support in Redis' Lua, so you can easily leverage that for targeted reads & writes.

The trade off, of course, are the compute resources needed for de/serializng.